# Can I add StretchDirection to a VisualBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to add the attribute StretchDirection to a VisualBrush?  My VisualBrush contains a media element, and the media element has this attribute, but not the VisualBrush.  When I apply the StretchDirection attribute to this MediaElement, it is ignored.  I am guessing because VisualBrush is overriding it's attributes.

```
  <VisualBrush x:Key="vb_zoneOneAdvertisement" TileMode="None" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" >
     <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <MediaElement />
     </VisualBrush.Visual>
  </VisualBrush>
```

Comment: it's seems to me a bit weird to use just a brush to render a MediaElement ? what is the reason and the goal of that ?

Comment: @GCamel - for performance reasons.  I need to run the same media file on multiple different windows, which in turn display on one to many monitors.  If I use a different media element, for each area I want to play the media file in, that's a lot of wasted CPU and memory.  With the mediabrush, I can run one media player and place the content in any window/space I wish without the loss of resources.

Comment: Hi, I make some try with my code - don't findout what you want to do with the direction - Stretch on the VisualBrush seems to be enough. By the way, direction is not usable because content is displayed in a viewbox in the VisualBrush. You have to adjust it to fit your need - Viewbox="0,0,0.5,0.5" or the ViewPort. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VisualBrush` takes ALL the content of `VisualBrush.Visual` and uses it as `Brush`. So imagine you use `Stretch="None"` with `Image` that is 10000x10000 in size, and you set this `VisualBrush` as `Background` of your `Window`. Like this code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListViewBasicSample" Height="500" Width="500">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <VisualBrush TileMode="None" AlignmentX="Center" Stretch="Fill" AlignmentY="Center" >
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Grid Background="red">
                        <Image Source="wp2444179.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" Margin="100" Height="10000" />
                    </Grid>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

You would expect, only a small part of this image to be rendered, but no, because ALL the content of `VisualBrush.Visual` is taken as `VisualBrush`. Here is the result:

[image]

**There is no place for `Stretch` property in this case.** You could use `margin`, `padding` or `TileMode` to make some small adjustments here. Possibly, add a `Container`(like `Grid`) for your `MediaElement` and define `Width` and `Height` for this `Container`.

**tl;dr;**
You asked if Stretch can be used on VisualBrush - it can be used, and it is properly taken into account, as in your example code. The problem is with `VisualBrush.Visual`. It makes (almost) no sense to use this property there, because all rendered `VisualBrush.Visual` is used as Brush. **I would say, the more you stretch, the more is used as Brush :)**